# Building C project with Allegro dependency

Tags: c, travis-ci, allegro

I have a [C project](https://github.com/rcook/elkulator/tree/p-rcook-cmake) that depends on Allegro that builds quite happily locally. I have been trying to set up Travis-CI integration for it and have run into problems with the Allegro dependency. Specifically:

- There is no `liballegro4-dev` pseudo-package: so I've changed my `.travis.yml` to refer to the specific `liballegro4.2-dev` package instead
- My CMake library detection does not work within Travis-CI: I have commented out the `check_library_exists(alleg al_trace "" HAVE_ALLEGRO)` from my `CMakeLists.txt` to move past this problem
- Within Travis-CI, I'm getting build errors which suggest that I need to reference various X11 libraries

My questions are:

- Has anybody successfully built an Allegro-based C project on Travis-CI? If so, can you point me at your `.travis.yml` file to get some inspiration?
- What is a valid library check for Allegro?
- Why does the package on Travis-CI have a dependency on X11 libraries while there seems to be no such dependency when I build on my local (Linux) machine?

[Here's](https://travis-ci.org/rcook/elkulator/builds/64950501) a link to my most recent failing Travis-CI build and [this](https://travis-ci.org/rcook/elkulator/builds/64855289) is another build which shows some of the X11-related failures to which I refer.

Comment: For your third question: Allegro indeed depends on X11. I suspect you're linking with a shared version on your local machine, but a static one on TravisCI (which would require linking with dependencies as well), but I can't confirm. You may need to either find another package, compile allegro from source with `-DSTATIC=OFF -DSHARED=ON`, or link with x11.

Comment: @CássioRenan: Thanks. I suspected it was something like this. Weird thing is that I just installed the standard `liballegro4.4-dev` on my local machine so I would've expected the linkage to be the same as the package on Travis-CI. I think I'll have to introduce a switch into my CMake configuration to create a build that can handle static dependencies.

Comment: @CássioRenan: Putting in the additional libraries `X11`, `Xcursor`, `Xxf86vm` and `Xpm` in my `target_link_libraries` does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer to my own question: adding the additional libraries `X11`, `Xcursor`, `Xxf86vm` and `Xpm` to my `target_link_libraries` declaration in `CMakeLists.txt` does the trick. I think @CássioRenan's suggestion that I'm getting the static instead of shared library on Travis-CI sounds about right.